# WorkManager Worker Class restarting work on app close

Tags: android, android-workmanager

For those familiar with WorkManager, is it normal for Work to be restarted when the app is closed (not Force Stopped, just regular swipe close)?

I have UniquePeriodicWork that starts every 15 minutes and takes a couple of minutes to complete. When I open my app while the Work has already started, the Work keeps progressing as normal, but when I swipe close the app, the Work is stopped and then it restarts from the beginning of doWork() seconds later. How can I have this work not be restarted from the beginning when I close my app? Thanks.

Comment: did you find anything about this?

Comment: @ElJazouli no. I stopped using WorkManager and instead used AlarmManager in combination with ForegroundService